# How do you install a frost-free garden faucet mid-wall?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a split level house, and have a garden on the side that's half underground. I want to install a frost-free faucet on that side of the house, but if I install it as instructed in the foundation wall, it'll only be a few inches off the ground, and if I install it in the rim joist between levels, it'll be 5 feet above ground.

How do you install a frost free faucet mid-wall through insulation and drywall?

Comment: Is there a living space on the other side of the wall at the height that you would like to install the hose bib ? Is there plumbing in that same location or in the wall near by ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan My laundry room is on the other side of the wall. The faucet would come out about head-height behind my stacked washer/dryer.

Answer (score 1):

...Provide framing/blocking to support it.

Cut a hole stud to stud in the drywall, add blocking between studs (like a one-stud-bay rim joist at a convenient height) and now you have something solid to mount your faucet to.

*...And, y'know, repair the wall after - put the insulation back in, repair the vapor barrier if needed, repair the drywall.*

Comment: I think the challenge being asked about is how to manage the depth (from the face of the outside wall) of a frost-resistant sillcock, which usually need 8-14 inches of depth.

Comment: They stick out of the exterior wall. That's why they are frost-free. If you don't want to see it, then pick a spot where you have an internal wall you can hide it in.